# Change language. "Add new announcement"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am wondering how to change the text below a list that says "Add new announcement" to something else. How would I go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: You will have to write script to replace text...

Answer (score 2):

A demo code for your reference:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("idHomePageNewAnnouncement").innerHTML = "Test";
}

</script>
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]